# react native could not connect to development server on android

Tags: android, react-native

I have started learning react native. I have followed instruction on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content
but when i try to run the app with command

```
react-native run-android
```

it gives me error

```
could not connect to development server :
URL:http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android$dev=true&hot=false&minify=false
```

now, all the points displayed by app red screen to fix this issue I have followed :

*package server is running and i can access it directly from computer browser ie http://localhost:8081

*my android device connected to computer has debugging enabled i checked it using **adb devices** command

*I cannot use **adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081** as i have android 4.4.4 ( but still i tried it and and it returned **closed** twice )

So How can I make my app access the development server and fix the red error screen issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution :)

I am on ubuntu 16, so, I used command **ip addr show** which gave me my computer ip address.

I used this ip address and I was able to access localhost on my mobile.

Finally I added the ip address and port no to devsettings  of android phone and My app was able to access development server

Comment: Cool, but if your'e phone and your computer aren't on the same network it won't work. In that case, I like using `ngrok` to create a tunnel to my computer.